# zip function in python 3.5 with more than 255 arguments

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.5

I have a zip function in the code giving me the error "SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments"

```
sentences_join = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(sentences[0::256], sentences[1::256], sentences[2::256], sentences[3::256], ..., sentences[255::256])]
```

How can I compress this function to have less than 255 arguments?

Comment: @dfundako the zip function is entirely different than zip compression.

Comment: Note that in python 3.7 you will be able to pass more than 255 arguments

Comment: yes, thank you, I have put in the question 3.5 because of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonic way of `apply`ing a function can turn an iterable into arguments:

```
sentences_join = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(*map(lambda i: sentences[i::256], range(256)))]
```

Comment: i need to import something for apply?

Comment: Oh, I missed it. You don't actually need `apply`, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sentences_join = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(*(sentences[n::256] for n in range(256)))]
```

Comment: it is missing something for the second "for"

Comment: @EduardoAndrade fixed